# MySQLdb import fails in terminal but works in eclipse

Tags: python, mysql-python

I tried to install MySQLdb using easy_install as well as PIP. It says it installed fine. When I try to run a script from the terminal it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./parsing_script.py", line 5, in <module>
import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

But the same script runs fine when I run it from within eclipse.
My VM is a Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.
Also I ran yolk to list the active packages and it shows MySQLdb as active.

```
rajul@ubuntu:~$ yolk -l
Mako            - 0.8.1        - active 
MarkupSafe      - 0.15         - active 
MySQL-python    - 1.2.5        - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages)
```

Also here is my python path and it does not seem to include dist-packages.Could that be the problem and if so how do I add it.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat- linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Something seems off here - I'm not seeing any entries for `/usr/lib/python2.7/*` Did you manually install Python 2.7 or are you using the default interpreter? What do you have for the shebang line in your script? (starts with `#!`) If you want to manually add the dist-packages directory you can do `sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")` above the import.

Comment: The shebang line is the correct python shebang. #!/usr/bin/env python
Also adding it via code does fix the issue but I would like to change the pythonpath instead.

Comment: You can manually export the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to add custom package locations to source but I wouldn't recommend it. What I suspect is happening is Eclipse is running with a different environment from your terminal. An easy way to see the difference in the environment is to put `import os; os.system("env")` at the top of your script and run it in both Eclipse and the terminal to compare.